# Any idea how to add this sinking hover effect to an image/link?

Tags: html, css

[Arrow(custom icon) I am trying to animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW1dU.jpg)

I've created an icon image of an arrow that is also a link. It is on top of a background image. When the mouse hovers over the arrow I'd like to create a **"sink"** effect similar to the one found in the 2d transitions section [here](https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/#). How can this be done?

My CSS/HTML thus far:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  height: 100vh;
}
.content {
  height: 150vh;
}
img#bg {
  z-index: -100;
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Set up positioning */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50;
  left: 45.5%;
}
h1#title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Tinker Time</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="assets/building2.jpg" id="bg" alt="" />
    <a href="#anchor">
      <img src="assets/arrow.png" id="arrow" alt="" />
    </a>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <a name="anchor"></a>
    <h1>Team Members, About us, Blog</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pardon, new to the site, thought this was an appropriate question. I've tried using that code with no success. The icons on his site aren't images which might be causing the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover code that's part of this lib should still work with an image, heres a working example with a random avatar icon:

```css
/* Sink */
.hvr-sink {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sink:hover, .hvr-sink:focus, .hvr-sink:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(8px);
  transform: translateY(8px);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img class="hvr-sink" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6fce102dc34236cd4e485c69d7293ee9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG"></img>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think OP wanted 'sink' not 'shrink'

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job if you are using the hover.css.

Just import the hover.css stylesheet into your HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hover.css">
```

and add this:

```
<img src="assets/arrow.png" id="arrow" alt="" class="hvr-sink" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, very simple version - could be an image if you want.

If that's all you want then don't need to include a singing and dancing library!

```css
.red_box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.red_box:hover {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="red_box"></div>
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate the response, got it working finally! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

1. Add hover.css to your html file,
2. Add hvr-sink class to your arrow image.

For example:

```
    <body>
    <header>
    <img src="assets/building2.png" id="bg" alt="" />
    <a href="#anchor">
      <img src="assets/arrow.png" class="hvr-sink" id="arrow" alt="" />
    </a>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
       <a name="anchor"></a>
        <h1>Team Members, About us, Blog</h1>
      </div>
   </body>
```